# Conversion from geographic to geomagnetic coordinates

Tags: java, coordinates

I'm trying to convert between geographic and geomagnetic coordinates. I've found the following Prolog script, but I don't understand it enough to convert it myself. The target language is Java, but anything understandable is fine (C, Python, VB, whatever).

http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/astro/geo2mag.pro

If someone could either help with the conversion of this script or explain what exactly it is doing (those array operations are baffling to me), I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: The script you found is not written in Prolog.

Comment: Upon further research, it may have something to do with ION Script instead: http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/What_Is_ION_Script.html

Comment: I am sure it is an idl script.  Those space folks like that alot.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the application, altitude can be an important variables in this coordinate conversion since geomagnetic coordinates are a mapping of the Earth's dipole magnetic field.

In Python you can easily convert geographic coordinates to geomagnetic (and vice versa) with SpacePy (http://sourceforge.net/projects/spacepy/).

Since you are looking for the source code to convert to Java, SpacePy is implementing the Fortran International Radiation Belt Environment Modeling (IRBEM) library, the source of which is available (http://irbem.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/irbem/web/index.html)

In Python, in case others are looking for a quick solution:

```
import spacepy.coordinates as coord
from spacepy.time import Ticktock
import numpy as np
def geotomag(alt,lat,lon):
    #call with altitude in kilometers and lat/lon in degrees 
    Re=6371.0 #mean Earth radius in kilometers
    #setup the geographic coordinate object with altitude in earth radii 
    cvals = coord.Coords([np.float(alt+Re)/Re, np.float(lat), np.float(lon)], 'GEO', 'sph',['Re','deg','deg'])
    #set time epoch for coordinates:
    cvals.ticks=Ticktock(['2012-01-01T12:00:00'], 'ISO')
    #return the magnetic coords in the same units as the geographic:
    return cvals.convert('MAG','sph')
```

Answer (score 3):

I made it to python code, and tried to verify with this website http://wdc.kugi.kyoto-u.ac.jp/igrf/gggm/index.html .  I found that

1. The magnetic pole is that for Year 1995.
2. Even if I set the above calculate to use value for 1995, i quite don't get correct match.

I used value for Kyoto, japan (35N, 135.45W).  The webpage calculated (25.18, -155.80).  I got (25.33580652, -155.82724011).  So I am not completely sure if this can be of real use...

```
import numpy as np

from numpy import pi, cos, sin, arctan2, sqrt, dot
def geo2mag(incoord):
    """geographic coordinate to magnetic coordinate:

        incoord is numpy array of shape (2,*)
        array([[glat0,glat1,glat2,...],
            [glon0,glon1,glon2,...])
        where glat, glon are geographic latitude and longitude
        (or if you have only one point it is [[glat,glon]])

        returns
        array([mlat0,mlat1,...],
            [mlon0,mlon1,...]])
        """

    # SOME 'constants'...
    lon = 288.59 # or 71.41W
    lat = 79.3
    r = 1.0

    # convert first to radians
    lon, lat = [x*pi/180 for x in lon,lat]

    glat = incoord[0] * pi / 180.0
    glon = incoord[1] * pi / 180.0
    galt = glat * 0. + r

    coord = np.vstack([glat,glon,galt])

    # convert to rectangular coordinates
    x = coord[2]*cos(coord[0])*cos(coord[1])
    y = coord[2]*cos(coord[0])*sin(coord[1])
    z = coord[2]*sin(coord[0])
    xyz = np.vstack((x,y,z))

    # computer 1st rotation matrix:
    geo2maglon = np.zeros((3,3), dtype='float64')
    geo2maglon[0,0] = cos(lon)
    geo2maglon[0,1] = sin(lon)
    geo2maglon[1,0] = -sin(lon)
    geo2maglon[1,1] = cos(lon)
    geo2maglon[2,2] = 1.
    out = dot(geo2maglon , xyz)

    tomaglat = np.zeros((3,3), dtype='float64')
    tomaglat[0,0] = cos(.5*pi-lat)
    tomaglat[0,2] = -sin(.5*pi-lat)
    tomaglat[2,0] = sin(.5*pi-lat)
    tomaglat[2,2] = cos(.5*pi-lat)
    tomaglat[1,1] = 1.
    out = dot(tomaglat , out)

    mlat = arctan2(out[2], 
            sqrt(out[0]*out[0] + out[1]*out[1]))
    mlat = mlat * 180 / pi
    mlon = arctan2(out[1], out[0])
    mlon = mlon * 180 / pi

    outcoord = np.vstack((mlat, mlon))
    return outcoord

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mag =  geo2mag(np.array([[79.3,288.59]]).T).T
    print mag  # should be [90,0]

    mag =  geo2mag(np.array([[90,0]]).T).T
    print mag  # should be [79.3,*]

    mag =  geo2mag(np.array([
        [79.3,288.59],
        [90,0]
        ]).T).T

    print mag  # should be [ [90,0]. [79.3,*] ]

    # kyoto, japan
    mag =  geo2mag(np.array([[35.,135.45]]).T).T
    print mag  # should be [25.18, -155.80], according to 
               # this site using value for 1995
               # http://wdc.kugi.kyoto-u.ac.jp/igrf/gggm/index.html
```

Comment: The geographic coordinates of Kyoto are: 35.011667N, 135.768333E. So that is East, not West.